# Competing Risks without Censoring

Tags: hazard, competing-risks

I am trying to estimate the probability that an entity goes from state $A$ to either state $B$, $C$, or $D$.  The probability should be dependent on how long the entity has been in state $A$.

My data has **no censoring** in that the entity must go to either state $B$, $C$, or $D$ and the transition times are precisely known.

I suspect that Weibull distributions are appropriate to model the hazard functions given a set of variables $x_i$.  The hazard rate for is then:

$h(t) = (\frac{v}{p})(\frac{t}{p})^{v-1}e^{\beta \cdot x_i}$

, where $v$ is the shape, $p$ is the scale, and $t$ is time.

I believe I may be able to train three Weibull distributions for each transition... $A$ to $B$, $A$ to $C$, and $A$ to $D$.  However, I am unsure how to tie the three distributions together in order to say something about the probability of ending up at $B$, $C$, or $D$ given a time $t$.  I am also unsure on how to appropriately format my training data sets for the three models.